# How to add TextInputLayout inside the LinearLayout by dynamically?

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-textinputlayout

I want to add TextInputLayout inside a linearlayout by dynamically. I can add TextView and EditText inside a linearLayout but I can't add TextInputLayout.
that is my LinearLAyout:

```
  <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
               android:id="@+id/userInformation_lnr">
```

I can add TextView and EditText by using following code block

```
LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.userInformation_lnr);
        for(int i = 0; i <oyuncuSayisi; i++ ){
            EditText et = new EditText(this);
            TextView tx = new TextView(this);
            tx.setText("Player "+(i+1));
            tx.setTextSize(19);
            tx.setTypeface(Typeface.defaultFromStyle(Typeface.BOLD_ITALIC));
            tx.setTextColor(this.getResources().getColor(R.color.silver));

            et.setHint((i+1)+".Enter Player Name");
            et.setHintTextColor(this.getResources().getColor(R.color.DarkGoldenrod));
            DrawableCompat.setTint(et.getBackground(), ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.silver));
            et.setTextColor(this.getResources().getColor(R.color.SteelBlue));
            et.setTypeface(Typeface.defaultFromStyle(Typeface.BOLD_ITALIC));
            et.setTextSize(17);
            et.setId((i+1));
            ll.addView(tx);
            ll.addView(et);
        }
```

But I dont know how to add TextInputLayout, How can add TextInputLayout inside the LinearLayout?

Comment: In the same way. What is your issue?

Comment: I don't know how to add TextInputLAyout

Comment: You can of cause add a TextInputLayout into a LinearLayout, but TextInputLayout only works when has a child of TextInputEditText. So add the TextInputLayout to your LinearLayout, and add an TextInputEditText to the TextInputLayout. Maybe this is your issue?

Comment: I added TextInputLayout but how can I add style ?

Answer (score 0):

The TextInputLayout need a TextInputEditText to work, you can make a custom view for your TextInputLayout, then add it to the LinearLayout.

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/tv_input_layout"
    style="@style/YourCustomStyle"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:errorEnabled="false"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    tools:hint="hint"
    tools:placeholderText="ex: hint">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/tv_edit_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:text="value" />

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

The class:

```
class CustomTextInputLayout @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context,
    attrs: AttributeSet? = null,
    defStyleAttr: Int = 0
) : TextInputLayout(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {

    init {
        View.inflate(context, R.layout.custom_input_layout, this)
        // set the other things you need
    }
}
```

Then add it to the linearLayout:

```
private fun createInput() {
        val view = CustomTextInputLayout(context)

        ll.addView(view)
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for your advice but I don't know Kotlin :( I use java language to develop my project

Answer (score 0):

You can decouple presentation and business logic, if you move presentation to xml file.

**input_layout.xml**

```xml
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:theme="@style/MyInputTheme"    <-- You can define here your theme or style
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

And create this by `LayoutInflater`:

```java
LinearLayout container = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.container);
LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.input_layout, container, true);
```

Comment: thanks for  your advice but I have a question. When I use your method how get input from TexInputLayut ? How can I set Id to TextInputLayout in this way?

Comment: @Neo you can set id to `TexInputLayut ` as for any another view by method `setId()`. `EditText` is the sole direct child of `TexInputLayut ` so you can get it by method `getChildAt(0)`

Comment: I create a xml which is name player. I add TextInputLayout in player.xml .  Then I inflate player.xml in the for loop to create as much textinputlayout as the user wants.Well, in order to get user inputs from the textinputlayouts I created, I have to give an id to the textinputlayouts. How can I pass this ID to textinputlayouts when inflating.

Comment: @Neo you can't pass id. You can define it in xml as usual or assign it when view created (inflated)

Comment: When I create with inflate, and user creates more than one TextInputLayout, how do I get the information entered by the user in TextInputLayout?

Comment: @Neo it's impossible to answer without knowledge about your infrastructure and technologies stack. I guess, it's out of this topic bounds. You should ask new question with detailed description.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67027584/how-can-i-set-style-to-textinputlayout-by-dynamically-in-android

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a `TextInputLayout` with inside a `TextInputEditText`.
Something like:

```
    LinearLayout myLayout = findViewById(R.id.userInformation_lnr);
    TextInputLayout til = new TextInputLayout(this);
    til.setHint("Label");
    TextInputEditText et = new TextInputEditText(til.getContext());
    til.addView(et);
    myLayout.addView(til);
```

[image]