# How Can I set style to TextInputLayout by dynamically in android?

Tags: android, styles, dynamically-generated, material-components-android, android-textinputlayout

I want to create TexInputLayout by dynamically. I can create TextInputLayout using following code block :

```
TextInputLayout til = new TextInputLayout(this);
EditText et = new EditText(this);
til.addView(et);
et.setHint("Enter");
information.addView(til);
```

information is name of my linear layout which I use in the project.

But I want to change style of the TextInputLaout which I created by dynamically, I want to use  @style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.

I tried the following code block to change style :

```
TextInputLayout till= new TextInputLayout(new ContextThemeWrapper(this, 
 R.style.Widget_MaterialComponents_TextInputLayout_OutlinedBox));
 EditText et = new EditText(this);
 til.addView(et);
 et.setHint("Enter");
 information.addView(til);
```

but these code is not working. How can add style to TextInputLayout which I created dynamically ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 2nd parameter of the `ContextThemeWrapper` is a theme overlay, not a style.

You can define in `attrs.xml` a custom attribute:

```
<attr name="customTextInputStyle" format="reference" />
```

then in your app theme:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.*">
    <!-- ..... -->
    <item name="customTextInputStyle">@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox</item>
</style>
```

and finally:

```
    TextInputLayout til = new TextInputLayout(this,null,R.attr.customTextInputStyle);
    til.setHint("Label");
    TextInputEditText et = new TextInputEditText(til.getContext());  //important: get the themed context from the TextInputLayout
    til.addView(et);
    buttonsLayout.addView(til);
```

[image]

Comment: it is not working :( I create an attrs.xml file in values and add your code block . after I add your style code into styles folder . I had to change name of the style . But my problem still continue :(

Comment: I did the same answer you shared, what could I have done wrong?

Comment: @Neo The name of the theme is not a problem, just use your theme adding the customTextInputStyle attribute. Are you using a material components theme? Are you using the 1.3.0 ?

Comment: I am using 1.1.0

Comment: When I update the version of the material, my problem persists and the TextInputlayouts that I created before were broken.

Comment: @Neo just tried in a new empty project and it works. Try to use it in an empty project, and post your app theme. If the previous TextInputlayouts are broken there is something wrong in your projetct.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230970/discussion-between-neo-and-gabriele-mariotti).